# Data Factory Help : CSV files in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, azure-data-factory

We are currently using PowerBI to connect to CSV files on sharepoint using 'Source = SharePoint.Files('

we now need to bring these files into the datawarehouse but i can't find a file sharepoint connector only a sharepoint list connect.

Is there a way to grab files from sharepoint using data factory, i just need to load them into a Azure SQL database?

thanks

Comment: Had the same problem some time ago and ended up using Logic Apps, rather than ADF. It appears that ADF can do it via OData linked service (or Office 365 connection), but could not get either to work at that time.

Answer (score 0):

I have not found an easy way for this. The authentification towards Sharepoint is challenging and then the download functionality is als challenging. As Andrii wrote about the use of Logic Apps, we are considering a similar approach as an alternative. Due to lack of time we have not investigated this direction, yet.